How can I get the insertion_time value of an object in an Azure queue
I need to get the insertion time of an object in the queue. I can get the message but that's not the goal, I just want to know how long the message has been in the queue
When I try message.insertion_time I receive this error "AttributeError: 'QueueMessage' object has no attribute 'insertion_time'"
my code in Python
queue_service = QueueServiceClient(storage_url,credential)
queue_cliente = queue_service.get_queue_cliente(queue_name)
messages = queue_client.peek_messages()

if messages:
  for message in messages:
     print(message.insertion_time)
else:
print("Empty list")


Based on the documentation here, the correct name of the property is inserted_on and not insertion_time. Please try by using that.
queue_service = QueueServiceClient(storage_url,credential)
queue_cliente = queue_service.get_queue_cliente(queue_name)
messages = queue_client.peek_messages()

if messages:
  for message in messages:
     print(message. inserted_on)
else:
print("Empty list")

